# Proof: Boundary point not in set implies limit point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Problem:**

Suppose that $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that if $\vec{x}\notin \Omega$ and $\vec{x}$ is a boundary point of $\Omega$, then $\vec{x}$ is a limit point of $\Omega$.

**Working:**

Suppose that $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\vec{x}$ be a boundary point of $\Omega$ such that $x\notin \Omega$. Since $\vec{x}$ is a boundary point of $\Omega$, we know that every ball around $\vec{x}$ contains points in $\Omega$ and points not in $\Omega$.

BLANK

Therefore, there exists some sequence $\left\{\vec{x_i}\right\}$ in $\Omega$ with limit $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{x_i} \ne \vec{x}$. Hence, $\vec{x}$ is a limit point of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should take a sequence of ball of radius $\dfrac{1}{n}$ around $x$, since each of these balls contain an element of $\Omega$, you can define a sequence of element $x_i \in B(x,\dfrac{1}{i}) \cap \Omega$ so that $d(x_i,x) < \dfrac{1}{i}$

This will give you your sequence which converges to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in \partial \Omega$, then for every $\epsilon >0$ you have $B(x,\epsilon)\cap (\Bbb R^n \setminus \Omega)\neq \varnothing$ and $B(x,\epsilon)\cap \Omega \neq \varnothing$.

We will use the $B(x,\epsilon)\cap \Omega \neq \varnothing$ part. Since $x \not\in \Omega$, this in fact says that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $(B(x,\epsilon)\setminus \{x\})\cap \Omega \neq \varnothing$, that is, $x \in \Omega'$.